# React Native Maps not centering the map on user location if it gets updated

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

This is the first time I'm working with maps in React Native. I've some initial values setup like:

```
    const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(38.889815);
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(-77.005900);
    const [heading, setHeading] = useState(0);

    const GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS = {
        pitch: 65,
        altitude: 100,
        zoom: 17,
    };

    const [camera, setCamera] = useState({
        center: {
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude
        },
        heading: heading,
        pitch: GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS.pitch,
        zoom: GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS.zoom,
        altitude: GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS.altitude
    });
```

Then I'm asking for user location

```
    function getCurrentLocation() {
        Geolocation.watchPosition(
            position => {
                const myLastPosition = myPosition;
                const myPosition = position.coords;
                if (myPosition != myLastPosition) {

                    setLatitude(myPosition.latitude)
                    setLongitude(myPosition.longitude)
                    setHeading(myPosition.heading)

                    setCamera(
                        {
                            center: {
                                latitude: myPosition.latitude,
                                longitude: myPosition.longitude
                            },
                            heading: heading,
                            pitch: GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS.pitch,
                            zoom: GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS.zoom,
                            altitude: GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS.altitude
                        }
                    )
                }
            },
            null,
            {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
            }
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getCurrentLocation()
    }, [camera])
```

And finally, I'm displaying the map as

```
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <MapView
                ref={(mapView) => { _mapView = mapView }}
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                scrollEnabled={false}
                pitchEnabled={false}
                rotateEnabled={false}
                loadingEnabled={true}
                moveOnMarkerPress={true}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                showsBuildings={false}
                showsCompass={true}
                showsMyLocationButton={false}
                followsUserLocation={true}
                style={styles.mapMain}
                userLocationPriority={'high'}
                minZoomLevel={GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS.zoom}
                maxZoomLevel={GEOLOCATION_OPTIONS.zoom}
                initialCamera={camera}>

            </MapView>
        </View >
```

The options which are true and false are basically there to stop the user from moving the app. The idea is that the map will update as per user location and will also rotate if the user heading is updated.

Now when I manually change the user location for the iOS simulator I'm running I do `Features > Location > Custom Location` and doing so I can see that the user location marker is moved to that position but the camera is not getting updated through the values of the state are also updated.

Also, the map doesn't rotate if the heading is updated.

What I'm trying to do is the same as navigation, it moves as the user moves and rotates when the user takes a turn.